# Why won't VirtualBox work?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I want to run VirtualBox so that I can use Windows Vista, but this is what pops up when I start it.

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing
>
> ```
> /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
> ```
>
> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

I don't know what it means, but I know I have to install something but don't know what to do.

Comment: what you want to install ?

Comment: i dont want to install anything i just want to run windows vsta

Comment: Did you even read the error message you received? This is one  of those rare cases where the error gives you the solution: "Please reinstall the kernel module by executing `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`
as root".

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

in Terminal. This is the installation script for kernel drivers. Also, you have to check if you have DKMS installed.

```
sudo apt-get policy dkms
```